# How to pass multiple bootstrap servers for listener using spring-kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a listener that need to read from multiple kafka servers with the same topic which are all configured under one zookeeper. How do I read from those multiple servers. Can you please help with this.

Instead of Kafka servers, can I point to zookeeper instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `@KafkaListener` requires `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` `@Bean`, which, in turn, is based on the `ConsumerFactory`. And the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` accepts a `Map<String, Object>` of consumer configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
                        kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ...);
        ...
        return props;
    }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#__kafkalistener_annotation

Where that `ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` is exactly standard Apache Kafka `bootstrap.servers` [property](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs):

> A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster. The client will make use of all servers irrespective of which servers are specified here for bootstrapping—this list only impacts the initial hosts used to discover the full set of servers. This list should be in the form host1:port1,host2:port2,.... Since these servers are just used for the initial connection to discover the full cluster membership (which may change dynamically), this list need not contain the full set of servers (you may want more than one, though, in case a server is down).

No, you can't point Zookeeper address. That isn't supported by Kafka any more.

Comment: The new (0.9+) client objective is to avoid client code having to talk to zookeeper. You could, however, (I presume) query zookeeper yourself to get the broker list and populate the bootstrap servers config property.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Also I believe Kafka has a topic called _consumer-offsets using which offset management between server and client is handled. So if I use multiple servers corresponding to multiple zookeepers, Will spring-kafka handle particularly the offset management.

Comment: Spring Kafka doesn't manage offsets. Everything is done on the Kafka Broker. We only provide `consumer.group` and rely on the offset provided for the Consumer instance.

Comment: Will I be able to use multiple servers from different Kafka clusters with same topic name?

Comment: I don't think so. Those `bootstrap.servers` are really must be in the same Kafka cluster. Even if your topic name is the same, physically they are different objects because they are in different clusters.

Comment: Are you sure about that Artem? Did you try/read it somewhere or is that just what you think?

Comment: What do you mean? The Kafka doc clearly states with the: `A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.`. So, all the brokers must be in the same cluster. Am I missing anything? And right, I didn't try that because my task not to find bugs in Apache Kafka

Answer (score 3):

The map has key: String and Value: Object.

The Object of key:ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG should be series of host-port pair seperated by ',' like: host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3 ......

e.g for listening three servers: localhost:9092,192.168.22.12:9088,localhost:7898